# How best to connect containers within Docker

Tags: mysql, docker, google-compute-engine

Do i always need to use the --link command to link to containers to one another or can i just ping the ip of the 2nd container from the 1st container.

Example:
Container 1 running mysql (tcp 3306) : ip 10.0.0.7
Container 2 running lamp : ip 10.0.0.8

can 0.8 not just directly connect to 0.7 they are on the same bridge ?

Thanks once again for the help

Regards

Hareem Haque

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, I added --icc=true to my docker opts and restarted docker. I just ran a test connecting a php container to a mysql container without using --link. Everything works great. I see no error. I can now easily connect containers together via bridge ip address.

Answer (score 2):

It depends even on your network topology.

If you choose "secure" setup with --icc=false you will have to use --link for dockers to communicate.

Documentation at [1] explains it.

Link:
[1] - https://docs.docker.com/articles/networking/#communication-between-containers

Regards
Paolo

Comment: Thanks @Paolo. Basically, I added --icc=true to my docker opts and restarted docker. I just ran a test connecting a php container to a mysql container without using --link. Everything works great. I see no error.

 I can now easily connect containers together via bridge ip address. 

Best Regards
Hareem Haque

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect containers on different hosts, the best option available right now is using Weave: 
https://github.com/zettio/weave
Another is Open vSwitch, but it's too messy for my taste. Docker's acquisition of SocketPlane could result in something usable, but we are not there yet. I would go with Weave.